# Android: ScrollView which contains textInput not scrolling

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, textinput

I have a scrollView which contains too many textInput. Everything is working until i add `textAlign: 'right'` to TextInput styles. After that ScrollView not response to scroll. This problem just occurred in android, in iOS it's work as expected. I added a simple code to the [snack.expo](https://snack.expo.io/r12IRcCg-)

```
  render() {
    let TextInput2 = (
      <TextInput
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          textAlign: 'right',
          height: 50
        }}
        placeholder="placeholder"
      />
    );
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
        {TextInput2}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have too many items in a `ScrollView` then maybe you should consider using [`ListView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html). I have had a similar issue. At some point after too many items to scroll, `ScrollView` starts to fail first in Android. I assume i-devices has a better optimization in terms of rendering react native components, which prevent them to fail early.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is textAlign: right. I add this code for just showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why textAlign: 'right' causes that, but I noticed a substantial difference between ios and android TextInput. On Android, if the TextInput box is smaller than the font size, it creates a scrollable TextInput inside itself, preventing the scrollview to be the responder. Try to increment the height and the width of each TextInput to be sure this is not the case.